# How to Update Meeting Content Format?

Tags: vba, outlook

With the VBA code below the content will only give plain text in the meeting body.

```
Sub test()    

     Dim myItem As Object
     Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
         
     Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
     myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
     myItem.Subject = "TestSubject"
     myItem.Location = "Place"
     myItem.Body = "Hi xxx" & vbCrLf & _
     "Kind reminder your seat has been confirmed. Please refer below for details." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     "Date&Time" & vbCrLf &  _
     "Venue" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     "Please let me know if you cannot make it.  Thank you." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     "With warm regards," & vbCrLf & _
     "Name" & _
     "Pan Asian Equity Sales" & vbCrLf & _
     'Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Nate Sun")
     'myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired
    
    myItem.Display
     
 End Sub
```

How do I update the email content format like the text color, bold, underline, etc. inside the meeting body?

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is VBA :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
.Body = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test}"
```

Found on [xtremevbtalk](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-91618.html)

**Edit**

Here is the full sub I used to test the string :

```
Sub testoApptItem()

Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set oAppointmentItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)


With oAppointmentItem
    .Body = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test}"
    .Subject = "test"
    .Start = Now
    .End = Now + 0.25
    .Location = ""
    .ReminderSet = False
    .Categories = "AM/PM Assigned"
    .Save

End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, it seems not working. I just copied your script to replace my current one. THe output will exactly show "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl 
;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test}" 
in the email body content when I run

Comment: Make sure you don't have a space between `colortbl` and the semicolon, I was able to change the body of my appointment with this code.

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it's correct without any space

Comment: Do you mind copy your full script you have tested successfully?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have copied paste your code into a new module to test, it still does not work. The result is still showing the whole code {\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test} in the appointment body content...

Comment: It's weird because it works fine on my Outlook 2016. If you go in the VB Editor and then in Tools\References, is there any reference missing? (It's written in capital letters like in this [example](https://ni.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/219200i9665EC2889DE1D6F/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999) )

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ApppoontmentItem.RftBody` property - it takes a variant  array of byte (not just a string).

Outlook 2016 also understands HTML on appointments, but OOM still does not expose `HTMLBody` property on the `ApppoontmentItem` object. You can try to set `PR_HTML` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102`) using ApppoontmentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to set the property in my vba code?

Comment: It will not work in VBA - there is a known bug that causes an error when the ApppoontmentItem.RftBody  property is set using late binding. You need to use early binding (which is impossible in a script). You can try to use Redemption - its SafeAppointmentItem object exposes RtfBody as a string).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry that i am beginner in vba so i may not understand your explanations which seems more than i can get, do you mean it is not possible to update the current vba code to change the appointment item body format ?